# Using Cayley-Hamilton and faithful modules to show $x\in B$ is integral over $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

This is from Proposition 5.1 from Atiyah and MacDonald's book. Suppose $B$ is a ring containing the ring $A$ and that $x\in B$. Also suppose there is a finitely generated, faithful $A[x]$-module $M$ which is finitely generated as an $A$-module. I want to show that $x\in B$ is integral over $A$.

Let $\phi \colon M \to M$ be multiplication by $x$, so $\phi(m) = xm.$ Then $\phi(M) \subseteq M = AM$ because $M$ is an $A[x]$-module, so closed by the action of $x$. So by Cayley-Hamiltion, there exist $a_1,\dots,a_n \in A$ such that $$\phi^n + a_1\phi^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n = 0$$ as a map on $M$.

Now $M$ is faithful, so for any $a \in A[x],$ we have that $a.m \neq 0$ for some $m \in M.$ In particular, $x^nm \neq 0$ for some $m \in M$. Then plugging $m\in M$ into the above equation, we get $$x^nm +a_1x^{n-1}m + \cdots + a_0m = 0.$$ But why does this imply that $x$ is integral over $A?$ We would need to get rid of the $m$, but I don't see how to do that.

Comment: @EricWofsey $B$ would be a ring containing both $x$ and $A$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Well if $B$ is a ring containing the ring $A$ surely $B$ would be an $A$-module by just defining $a.b$ to be the multiplication in $B$, so $B$ would be an $A$-algebra?

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, sorry, I thought I had written those stuff but slipped past me while I was writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing is that actually you know that $$x^nm +a_1x^{n-1}m + \cdots + a_nm = 0$$ for *all* $m\in M$.  That is, writing $y=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots+a_n\in A[x]$, you know that $ym=0$ for all $m\in M$.  Since $M$ is faithful over $A[x]$, this implies $y=0$.